# Bigquery Client Insertion Security

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create an event tracking system for our website. I would like to insert the events into Bigquery directly from the consumer's browser. However, to do this, I believe that I need to share the API key with the browser for it to be able to insert into Bigquery. This creates a security flaw, where someone can take the API key and insert large volumes of false events into our Bigquery tables. Are there security features on the Bigquery server that can filter out such events (perhaps by detecting malicious insertion patterns)?

Comment: inserting directly from client side is not a good idea e.g. error handling etc. You should send the request server side for asyn processing to BigQuery.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to batch the requests with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

See the solution "How to Do Serverless Pixel Tracking":

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/serverless-pixel-tracking-tutorial

Instead of logging straight to BigQuery, you could:

- Create a pixel in Google Cloud Storage.
- Insert this pixel in your pages.
- Configure GCS logs so they are routed to BigQuery - in realtime through StackDriver.
- Even add a load balancer, for best performance around the world.